# Remove the ID or text of the element that fires

Tags: jquery

is there any way to remove the ID or text of the element that fires.For now firing on button adds/remove selected text, but if we clicked more than one, text from clicked button adds to list,when i second clicked on selected button, removes all text from list, but i need remove only selected.Any solution?

***jQuery***

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var txt = "";
    $("#_button").children().toggle(function() {

        txt = $(this).text();
        $(this).css("background", "blue");
        $("#place").append("<td>" + txt + "</td>");

    }, function() {

        $("#place").children(this).remove();
        $(this).css("background", "red");

    });
});
```

***HTML***

```
<ul id="_button">
     <li id="a" value="30">a</li>
     <li id="b" value="30">b</li>
     <li id="c" value="30">c</li>
</ul>
<table>
     <tr id="place">
     </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can look for the element's text being toggled and only remove the corresponding `td` with the following code using `:contains()` selector.

Change this

```
$("#place").children(this).remove();
```

to

```
$("#place").children(':contains('+$(this).text()+')').remove();
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/gptG5/1/

Read more on [`:contains() Selector`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jquery contains selector to select the table cell with matching text to the list item clicked:

```
txt=$(this).text();
$("#place").children(":contains("+ txt +")").remove();
```

I have created a fiddle for it to show it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cQWDr/).

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var txt="";        
$("#_button li").toggle(function(){
         txt=$(this).text();
         $(this).css("background","blue"); 
         var id = $(this).attr('id');       
         $("#place").append("<td class="+id+">"+txt+"></td>");
},function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');        
    $("#place").find('td.' + id).remove();
    $(this).css("background","red");
});
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZPtqm/1/)

Answer (score 0):

The following code will do it. Here's the JSFiddle to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/leniel/JqZc6/

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var txt = "";        

    $("#_button").children().toggle(function()
    {
        txt = $(this).text();

        $(this).css("background","blue");  

        $("#place").append("<td>"+txt+"</td>");

    },function()
    {
        txt = $(this).text();

        $("#place").children("td:contains('"+txt+"')").remove();

        $(this).css("background","red");
    });
});
```